# sql error near near 'getLastRecord ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT'

Tags: mysql

Hello guys how do I search through a table for an amount from the same user getting the last updated transaction? Below statement has a problem

```
SELECT `Amount` 
from `contributions` 
where `MemberName` like "KEL" getLastRecord 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT;
```

Comment: `getLastRecord` is out of place, and I can't even guess where it belongs based on your current question.  Sample data and output would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You have  a wrong sequence of double quote and a wrong getlastRecord   try

```
SELECT Amount 
from contributions 
where MemberName like "KEL" 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

for a better use of like  you could use wildchar

```
SELECT Amount 
from contributions 
where MemberName like "%KEL%" 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

otherwise you should use

```
SELECT Amount 
from contributions 
where MemberName = "KEL" 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: `LIKE "KEL"` ? Surely `= 'KEL'` or `LIKE 'KEL%'`

Comment: .@RiggsFolly  .. thanks  .. answer  updated  with suggestion for like and =

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Amount from contributions 
where MemberName like '%KEL%'  
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Also you can add the `%` to act as a wildcard.

```
'%Kel%' any string that contains the sequence 
'%Kel' any string that ends with that sequence
'Kel%' any string that starts with the sequence
```

if u are just looking to search by the name 'Kel'

```
SELECT Amount from contributions 
where MemberName = 'KEL'  
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

you don't need the `LIKE` for this